# ViewersObservables.observeInput(Viewer) example?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, jface, eclipse-databinding

Can anybody point me to an example which is dealing with Databinding of jface viewers with the ViewersObservables.observeInput(Viewer)?

Am looking to update the contents of a viewer (the items in the comboviewer) with some dynamic content (new set of items to the comboviewer)

Any pointers is much apreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide a bit of my (working code):

```
libraryPathsObservable = BeansObservables.observeDetailValue(selectedToolkit, "libraryPath", Object.class);
bindingContext.bindValue(ViewersObservables.observeInput(libraryPaths), libraryPathsObservable);
```

Contents provider for `libraryPath` is `ArrayContentProvider` and `selectedToolkit.getLibraryPath` actually returns `String[]`